# Run Windows Desktop Applications Under The Linux Sub-System

Tags: java, windows, kotlin, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A while back I made a switch from C# to Kotlin. Initially I was using Windows 10, but moving to Kotlin highlighted some of the limitations in Windows; notably long Java class paths, and the Windows 280 character limit.

I know there are workarounds to get shorter class paths, like rolling them up into a JAR file, but for the project I was working on (building CorDapps with Corda), none of the workarounds...worked. *This was due to some internal code in Corda, which loaded JAR files from the class path using reflection, however the code didn't recursively check **those** JAR files for class paths.*

I eventually switched to Ubuntu and then MacOS and these problems were no more, since neither OS suffers from such limits. However, Windows now has WSL/WSL2 so I can install Ubuntu as a subsystem in Windows 10. That got me thinking...

**Is it possible to run Windows applications in the context of a linux system on WSL?**

To elaborate on my question, I'd like to be able to run IntelliJ IDEA on Windows as my IDE for Kotlin, but have it consume the JDK installed under a WSL Ubuntu instance, and also execute Kotlin applications under the same instance. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Does this help? https://petri.com/how-to-install-linux-gui-apps-in-windows-10-21h2-with-wsl

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA will get this feature in the next release (2021.2), you can try its EAP version now (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/05/intellij-idea-2021-2-eap-1/)